# How to call Domain's method which the Domain name is in variable using grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am writing a controller method which needs to pass a string param as the Domain name and int param as the key, then use `Domain.get(id)` to get the Domain instance.

Could anyone show me how to do it? I've tried

`${params.DomainName}.get(params.DomainId as int)`

but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getDomainClass() for this purpose.

```
def className = params.domainName  //com.somepackage.MyClass
def clazz = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(className).clazz
def entry = clazz.get(params.long('domainId'))
```